# Find duplicates from different nested JSON Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a huge JSON structure looking like this.

```
{
  "Collection":[
    {
    "field0":"string",
    "field1":"string",
    "field2":"string",
    "field3":"string",
    "field4":"string",
    "field5":"string",
    "field6":"string",
    "field7":"string",
    "field8":"string",
      "field9":[
         "test1",
         "test2",
         "test3"
       ]
    },
    {
    "field0":"string",
    "field1":"string",
    "field2":"string",
    "field3":"string",
    "field4":"string",
    "field5":"string",
    "field6":"string",
    "field7":"string",
    "field8":"string",
      "field9":[
         "test4",
         "test2",
         "test5"
       ]
    },
    {
    "field0":"string",
    "field1":"string",
    "field2":"string",
    "field3":"string",
    "field4":"string",
    "field5":"string",
    "field6":"string",
    "field7":"string",
    "field8":"string",
      "field9":[
         "test7",
         "test8",
         "test9"
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What i want is to find and print only the duplicates based on the nested arrays.

Like this:

```
{
  "Collection":[
    {
    "field0":"string",
    "field1":"string",
    "field2":"string",
    "field3":"string",
    "field4":"string",
    "field5":"string",
    "field6":"string",
    "field7":"string",
    "field8":"string",
      "field9":[
         "test1",
         "test2",
         "test3"
       ]
    },
    {
    "field0":"string",
    "field1":"string",
    "field2":"string",
    "field3":"string",
    "field4":"string",
    "field5":"string",
    "field6":"string",
    "field7":"string",
    "field8":"string",
      "field9":[
         "test4",
         "test2",
         "test5"
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to do this so i can check which duplicates should i delete cause only the nested arrays has duplicates.

I would provide a work of mine but i cant find anything and i am not used to Python.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your code so far?

Comment: @SebastienD unfortunately i haven't done anything cause I am not used to python and i cant find anything for different arrays.

Comment: You can read the JSON into a python dict using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: What do you consider a duplicate? It is not obvious to me how the first block transforms to the second.

Comment: Take note that none of your examples are valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will iterate through and check if any item in the nested list is also found in another nested list. It'll then collect their index positions then reconstruct the dictionary using only those index positions. As long as your json follows this format, it should work:

```
example = {
  "Collection":[
    {
    "field0":"string",
    "field1":"string",
    "field2":"string",
    "field3":"string",
    "field4":"string",
    "field5":"string",
    "field6":"string",
    "field7":"string",
    "field8":"string",
      "field9":[
         "test1",
         "test2",
         "test3"
       ]
    },
    {
    "field0":"string",
    "field1":"string",
    "field2":"string",
    "field3":"string",
    "field4":"string",
    "field5":"string",
    "field6":"string",
    "field7":"string",
    "field8":"string",
      "field9":[
         "test4",
         "test2",
         "test5"
       ]
    },
    {
    "field0":"string",
    "field1":"string",
    "field2":"string",
    "field3":"string",
    "field4":"string",
    "field5":"string",
    "field6":"string",
    "field7":"string",
    "field8":"string",
      "field9":[
         "test7",
         "test8",
         "test9"
       ]
    }
  ]
}


repeat_idx = []    
for idx, each in enumerate(example['Collection']):
    for k, v in each.items():
        if type(v) == list and len(v) > 1:
            nested_list = v

            for idx2, each2 in enumerate(example['Collection']):
                if idx == idx2:
                    continue

                for k2, v2 in each2.items():
                    if type(v2) and len(v2) > 1:
                        if len([i for i in nested_list if i in v2]):
                            if idx not in repeat_idx:
                                repeat_idx.append(idx)


repeats = {}
repeats['Collection'] = []

for idx in repeat_idx:
    repeats['Collection'].append(example['Collection'][idx])
```

**Output using pprint:**

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(repeats)


{'Collection': [{'field0': 'string',
                 'field1': 'string',
                 'field2': 'string',
                 'field3': 'string',
                 'field4': 'string',
                 'field5': 'string',
                 'field6': 'string',
                 'field7': 'string',
                 'field8': 'string',
                 'field9': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']},
                {'field0': 'string',
                 'field1': 'string',
                 'field2': 'string',
                 'field3': 'string',
                 'field4': 'string',
                 'field5': 'string',
                 'field6': 'string',
                 'field7': 'string',
                 'field8': 'string',
                 'field9': ['test4', 'test2', 'test5']}]}
```